# UITableViews and Asynchronous Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uitableview, afnetworking

I am using some sort of UI which you can assume it is a `UITableView` (please do not suggest `UITableView` frameworks because what I am using is not a `UITableView` but functions very similarly.

I am using `AFNetworking` to asynchronously download images, in which I store into an array. in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I am populating the contents of that array. The problem however, is that the data does not finish downloading until after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called causing a crash.

What's the best way to handle asynchronous data download, while populating a UI similar to the table view?

Comment: How about supplying a "placeholder" image which is replaced once the remote data is fully downloaded?

Comment: Are you populating UIImageViews with these images?

Comment: Why don't you return a default image when you don't have access yet to your image from your network?

Comment: ok i just saw Till idea I guess we have the same idea in mind

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, return the cell with a placeholder image, and keep a reference to it's index. When you finally got the image just reload that cell. UITableView will only reload it if it is visible, and now you'll have the image.

Comment: Problem is that I do not know beforehand how many "cells" there are. I am trying to find a way to break from the synchronous assumption and use proper asynchronous methods. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you don't know how many cells you have, just show a loading or something, then when you have the cells call reloadData on the table view. If it's incremental like the Facebook app, just insert one by one as you get them.